# Redis: getting the previous n elements relatively to a given element in Sorted Set

Tags: sorting, redis

I have a Sorted Set in Redis that stores my data by score and everything works fine so far.

The scores are timeseries and the data is a string Id. What I want is to get the previous 3 elements relatively to a given element sorted by time.

As an example, my Sorted Set `"ids_by_time"` contains these data (sorted by reverse score) :

```
50000 "rev75" 
49055 "rev95" 
49050 "rev25"
49025 "rev11"
49015 "rev500"
49000 "rev1"
48105 "rev22"
48000 "rev300"
47999 "rev74"
47345 "rev33"
47255 "rev11"
46288 "rev5"
```

Is it possible to get with this query Redis Sorted Set to get the 3 previous in the order to `"rev1"`? in this case the result would be `"rev22", "rev300" and "rev74"` in this order (the reverse)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish the above, you first need to know the "given element"'s rank - this is easily obtained with the [`ZREVRANK`](https://redis.io/commands/zrevrank) command. Then, use the reply to compute the ranks of the relevant elements' range and obtain it with [`ZREVRANGE`](https://redis.io/commands/zrevrange), i.e. if the rank is `n` you'll need to use a range of of `n+1` to `n+3` for the next 3 elements. Like so:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> ZREVRANGE ids_by_time 0 -1
 1) "rev75"
 2) "rev95"
 3) "rev25"
 4) "rev500"
 5) "rev1"
 6) "rev22"
 7) "rev300"
 8) "rev74"
 9) "rev33"
10) "rev11"
11) "rev5"
127.0.0.1:6379> ZREVRANK ids_by_time rev1
(integer) 4
127.0.0.1:6379> ZREVRANGE ids_by_time 5 7
1) "rev22"
2) "rev300"
3) "rev74"
```

You can always wrap that in a Lua script that will ensure both atomicity and minimal network traffic. For example:

```
~$ cat script.lua 
local rank = redis.call('ZREVRANK', KEYS[1], ARGV[1])
return redis.call('ZREVRANGE', KEYS[1], rank+1, rank+tonumber(ARGV[2]))
~$ redis-cli --eval script.lua ids_by_time , rev1 3
1) "rev22"
2) "rev300"
3) "rev74"
```

Comment: This is a great solution, but the first paragraph is completely unnecessary. This is not straightforward solution that you will find with a quick check on the manual; and it's a valid, specific and well formulated question.

Comment: @NazarenoLorenzo thanks for the feedback - edited the unnecessary paragraph away.